# VB.Net Listbox Arrows Change Selected Item

Tags: vb.net

So I have this listbox populated by this code

```
Dim Com3 As MySqlCommand
    Connection.Open()
    Com3 = New MySqlCommand("SELECT Payment_Type, ID FROM tbl12PaymentType ORDER BY Payment_Type DESC;", Connection)
    Com3.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim MSDA3 As New MySqlDataAdapter(Com3)
    Dim DT3 As New DataTable()
    MSDA3.Fill(DT3)
    ListBox2.DataSource = DT3
    ListBox2.DisplayMember = "Payment_Type"
    Connection.Close()
```

Now listboxes have an up and down arrow to go through the list but unless you actually click on the item, the selected item remains the same. What I would like to do is that with each click up or down the item selected changes.

I tried to change the selected items with the Key Up and Key Down event thinking those were the buttons but it made no difference as those don't refer to the buttons but the KEYS.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the KeyUp and KeyDown events?

Comment: Hi Mary! No those actually don't work. I'm talking about the little arrows (buttons?) That show up in textboxes when they are shrunk to show only one item at a time. When I click on those I can cycle through the list but the item showed is not the item selected. I would like to make so that when I click on it to show the next item it also selects it not just show it. Right now I have to click up or down and click on the item. I tried the KeyUp and KeyDown events but that didnt work.

Comment: What you are seeing is a scroll bar shrunken to show only the up down arrows. If your list box was a bit larger you would see the familiar scroll bar. Of course scrolling through the items in the list box does not select them. If you are presenting your list box so that only a single items is visible, you probably need to be using a combo box. A user can select an item with arrow keys on the keyboard or a click.

Comment: Oh you're right thanks!